# A possible invariant associated to a compact group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, polynomials, group-actions

Let $G$ be a compact topological group with normalized Haar measure $\mu$.

> Is there an effective isometric action of $G$ on some $\mathbb{R}^n$  such that the following map would be a non-irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$?

> $$P(X)=\int_G \langle X, \; g.X\rangle,\qquad  X\in \mathbb{R}^n$$

A motivational example is the permutational action of the finite group $G$ generated by cyclic permutation $(1,2,\ldots,n)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. For this action the above map $P$ has the  formula

$$P(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n)^2}{n}$$

My initial motivation was the following:

I encountered the inquality $n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \geq (\sum_{=1}^n x_i)^2$. To prove this I realized that the right hand side of this inequality  has the expansion $\sum_{i=0}^n <X, g^i.X>$ where  $g$ is the cyclic permutation $g=<2,3,\ldots,n,1>$. Then I applied Cauchy Schwartz inequality. So this leads me to be interested in the term $\int_G <X, gX>$ in present of a group action. According to the comment of Prof. Valette I realized that this integral is $|Q(x)|^2$ where $Q$ is projection on the space of fixed points of $G$.

My reason to emphasis on effectiveness was that: for trivial action we get the irreducible polynomial. Now thanks to the comment of Prof. Valette  I realize that the only non irreducible case is when the space of $G$ fixed vectors  is a  1 dimensional space.

> If the answer to the above question is yes one may associate an invariant to a  compact in particular finite group $G$ equal to the minimum of all possible $n$ with the above mentioned effective isometric action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> What is this function $P$ when $G$ is the whole group $O(n)$?

> What is the ideal generated by all polynomials $P$ obtained in this way via finit subgroups of $O(n)$?

Comment: By very simple reasons there is not even an effective action. Let $A$ be a non-trivial finite group and let $K=A^I$ for some set $I$. The cardinality of $K$ can be made arbitrarily large, i.e., larger than the set of permutations on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Echo  In your comment is not a possible confusion of effective action with free action?Please read the motivational example again

Comment: No. As soon as the cardinality is large enough the group homomorphism has a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: @Echo I think your first semtence in your first comment is not true because we jave effective action

Comment: The operator $\int_G gd\mu(g)$ is the orthogonal projection $Q$ on the space of G-fixed vectors. Hence $P(X)=\|Q(X)\|^2$ is à quadratic form.

Comment: @AlainValette  Thank you very much for your very helpful answer

Comment: No there are cases without an effective action. Effectivity means that the group homomorphism $G\to Per(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is injective. Now if the cardinality of $G$ exceeds the one of $Per(\mathbb{R}^n)$, there cannot be an effective action.

Comment: @Echo thank you for your comment. But in the question we requiere that action is by isometry not exclusively by permutation. In the example we have permutation but in general we work with isometry. I think the answer of Prof. Valette completes the answer to this question since it explicitly represent the quadratic form

Comment: The term $Per(X)$ for any set $X$ means the group of all bijective maps $X\to X$.

Comment: The answer to your question is no, since there is not always an effective action. The fact that the polynomial is a quadratic form doesn't make it irreducible.

Comment: @Echo  Ok in this sense only very  huge groups does not admit injective morphisms $G\to Per(|mathbb{R}^n}$

Comment: @Echo I've never seen this notation (while often encountering the notation $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ or $S_X$, or $\mathfrak{S}_X$). Are there papers where this notation $\mathrm{Per}(X)$ is used for the group of permutations of $X$? (I'm just curious since I tried to have an overview of them.)

Comment: @YCor I think "Sym" is  more popular since the notation $S_n$ used for  symmetric group but every element of $S_n$ is called a permutation.

Comment: The cardinality obstruction is not the only one. For instance, $\mathrm{Sym}_{\mathrm{fin}}(Y)$ (group of finitely supported permutations of $X$) does not embed into $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ if $|Y|>|X|\ge \aleph_0$. This is a result of Higman and De Bruijn. If $Y$ has cardinal $2^{|X|}$ these groups have the same cardinal.

Comment: @Echo: The way I read the question, $n$ is allowed to depend on $G$. However, your objection seems to just be the obvious point that, for fixed $n$, there may not be a faithful action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Perhaps I misunderstood something, but if I'm right then I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: By the way, the self-homeomorphism group of $\mathbf{R}^n$ for $n\ge 1$ has cardinal $c$ (unlike the whole permutation group, which has cardinal $2^c$). This is just because every continuous self-map is determined by its restriction to $\mathbf{Q}^n$.

Comment: @HJRW: Even if $n$ depends on $G$, if the cardinality of $G$ exceeds the cardinality of the union of all $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, then there is no efective action on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$.

Comment: @YCor: The notation Per(X) is the one I learned. For long time, I didn't know any other. I still find it the best. The letter $S$ is also used for spheres. Further, I do not know why the permutation group is also called symmetric group? Is there an asymmetric group? Aren't groups and symmetries essentially synonymous? Also, the letters Sym are also used for symmetric matrices (here the word symmetric makes sense!)

Comment: @Echo: Oh I see your point. This is a very “unreasonable” counterexample, though. Presumably the OP, like most mathematicians, implicitly wants some kind of cardinality upper bound.

Comment: @HJRW  Thank you  very  much for  your attention to my question. Yes, as  you wrote, $n$ is allowed to  depend on $G$. For  finite  group  $G$ we have an effective  action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}^{|G|}$ since $G$ is  embedded in $S_{|G|}$. So, according to the update version of the question, I think we may define  the following  invariant associated to group: The minimum of  all $n$ for which there exists an effective action of  $G$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the  space of  $G$ fixed vector  is a one  dimensional space. Some how similar to irreducible representation.

Comment: I dont know if this  invariant is well defined and helpful or no?